# "The requested module './login.js' does not provide an export named 'loggedIn'

Tags: javascript, import, export

I'm trying to export a boolean from one file to another for a login system. However, it's giving me this error. This is all happening on the front end javascript files, so I'm not sure if me using NodeJS on the backend has anything to do with it.

Also loggedIn is a boolean that's set to false right at the beginning of the file, and only set to true through an if statement in that file. So it always has a value no matter what.

I've tried looking online and it seems like there's a lot of different ways to do this and none of them are working for me.

Here's the export code:

```
module.exports = {loggedIn}; //Export the loggedIn status for the client.js file to use
```

And the import code:

```
import {loggedIn} from './login.js';

console.log(loggedIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do module.export in front-end javascript files. Instead use simple export keyword. Like this :

```
      export { loggedIn } ;
```

Comment: Check this out for more info : https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: That gives me 'unexpected token 'export' as an error.

Comment: Yep, and all the files involved are front end. login.js interacts with the back end but that's it.

Comment: One more question, are you using the any framework/library or the client.js file is directly defined inside a script tag with html code.

Comment: No it's all just defined in it's own files. I figured it out though, export {loggedIn} worked. My problem with that was it was inside an event listener for the login button, so it never got called if that button wasn't pressed. Moving it out fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Like the answer above I had to use export {loggedIn}. However, I also had the export code inside an event listener for a login button. Moving it outside of that event listener fixed the issue.